# How to calculate days till some point in future in PHP?

Tags: php, date

I've a date like this: `2011-01-28 00:37:15`.
What would be the most efficient way to get days from now till this date? I want like number of full days till this date so I could display message: "after X days" rather than showing ugly date.

I am using php 5.2.6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?

$date = "2011-01-28 00:37:15";
$date_2 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$date_diff=(strtotime($date)-strtotime($date_2)) / 86400;

?>
```

Comment: This should have round() on the last line, but it works! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at http://de.php.net/manual/de/datetime.diff.php (PHP >=5.3.0)

This will return you a DateIntervall wich has a public attribute days

Comment: I would like to use this method, but I'm on php 5.2.6. :(

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2011-01-28 00:37:15');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('now');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%d days');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this should help:

http://www.prettyscripts.com/code/php/php-date-difference-in-days