# How generate dates automatically using php?

Tags: date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate days till some point in future in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554667/how-to-calculate-days-till-some-point-in-future-in-php)

I'd want to generate dates from a start date to end date using PHP.
For example the start date is Jan 23, 2012 and the end date is Jan 30, 2012.
  I want the dates to be generated as
  Jan 24, 2012,
  Jan 25, 2012,
  .....
  .....
  Jan 30, 2012

Any help, pls...

Comment: With minor alterations, the answer in the question [How to calculate days till some point in future in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554667/how-to-calculate-days-till-some-point-in-future-in-php) can be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$fromDate = '01/23/2012';
$toDate = '01/30/2012';

$dateMonthYearArr = array();
$fromDateTS = strtotime($fromDate);
$toDateTS = strtotime($toDate);

for ($currentDateTS = $fromDateTS; $currentDateTS <= $toDateTS; $currentDateTS += (60 * 60 * 24)) {
    // use date() and $currentDateTS to format the dates in between
    $currentDateStr = date("Y-m-d",$currentDateTS);
    $dateMonthYearArr[] = $currentDateStr;
    //print $currentDateStr."<br />";
}

echo  "<pre>";
print_r($dateMonthYearArr);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```